# Show/Hide child table(html) on selection radio button in master table

Tags: html, animation, html-table

I have requirement where on selecting radio button in the main table a child table has to appear below. Any help?

---

Thanks for the reply, this is my actual requirement.I have two tables Item attributes and  Item attributes values. Onclicking  Item attributes (i.e)e.g: ticket height checkbox the child table of ticket height should display. Like wise there will be 10 item attributes and its respective item attribute values. So on clicking each item attribute the child attr value table should display.

Comment: Can you post code snippet? Your child table is inside your main table or what?

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to the child table.

```
<table id=`childTable`>
...
</table>
```

Add an onclick handler to the radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="radShowChild" onclick=showHideChild()>
```

Add a javascript function to do the hiding

```
function showHideChild()
{
   document.getElementById("childTable").style.visibility = "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

If you want to display specific "child" tables based on the radio button selected, pass the child table id as a parameter to the `showHideChild()` function.